# Unable to change the user password after cognito authentication

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, authentication, passwords, amazon-cognito

I created the user using [adminCreateUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminCreateUser-property). On trying to authenticate using [adminInitiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminInitiateAuth-property), a challenge `NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED` is returned. How do I change the password?

I am trying to reset the user password for a user with status `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD`, using the following snippet:

```
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.respondToAuthChallenge({
        ChallengeName: 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED',
        ClientId:'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        ChallengeResponses: {
                NEW_PASSWORD: 'T.YpkKu487',
                USERNAME: 'XXXXX'
        },
        Session: "cMcKC5ymFvZG2D10lJMRArpfmLZvnQE25P1XjwkHtl47g4kW-LAjOgB4CAjIgv1CurDmfRHpxzvYgYE61BBrp5-TNyVQcXXX"
}, (err, data) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(data);
});
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
InvalidParameterException: Invalid attributes given, name is missing
```

I do not understand this. Why am I getting this error? [Reference doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#respondToAuthChallenge-property)

Also, is there a way I could disable this challenge altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Found A solution: When I created the user pool I added name and email as required attributes, creating it without requiring attribute name solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the 'name' attribute in your "userattributes" which you will pass for changing the password
.